# CSS Hide text content of an attribute

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I've got the following HTML:

```
<td class="total">
  <span class="tooltip" data-tip-text="This is a tooltip">
    <span class="amount">
      <bdi><span class="currency-symbol">$</span>99.00</bdi>
    </span>
  </span>               
</td>
```

Would it be possible either with CSS or jQuery to hide or disable only the content of the `[data-tip-text]`?

So I need to remove the text that says "This is a tooltip" without affecting the Price span.

Comment: The text *This is a tooltip* isn't content and doesn't show in page, that is attribute. So use `$('.tooltip').removeAttr('data-tip-text')` to removing that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery provides a `removeAttr` function. Check the [doc](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) here

```
$(".tooltip").removeAttr("data-tip-text");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```js
//$('.tooltip').attr('data-tip-text', '')
//Use the above one to just make it empty

$(".tooltip").removeAttr("data-tip-text");
//Use this to remove it
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<td class="total">
  <span class="tooltip" data-tip-text="This is a tooltip">
    <span class="amount">
      <bdi><span class="currency-symbol">$</span>99.00</bdi>
    </span>
  </span>               
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply target the `dataset` attribute and set it to nothing. This will keep the data attribubte but set it so there is no string set in the attribute. `dataset.tipText = '';`

```js
const tooltip = document.querySelector('.tooltip');
// checking if it does not exist in a conditional will be falsey 
if(!tooltip.dataset.tipText){
  console.log(`before: !tooltip.dataset.tipText = ${true}`);
}else{
  console.log(`before: !tooltip.dataset.tipText = ${false}`);
}
console.log(`before: ${tooltip.dataset.tipText}`);

console.log(tooltip.dataset)

// now lets change the attribute to be empty and the same
// conditional is now truthy
tooltip.dataset.tipText = '';
console.log(`after: ${tooltip.dataset.tipText}`);
console.log(tooltip.dataset)

if(!tooltip.dataset.tipText){
  console.log(`after: !tooltip.dataset.tipText = ${true}`);
}else{
  console.log(`after: !tooltip.dataset.tipText = ${false}`);
}
```

```html
<td class="total">
  <span class="tooltip" data-tip-text="This is a tooltip">
    <span class="amount">
      <bdi><span class="currency-symbol">$</span>99.00</bdi>
    </span>
  </span>               
</td>
```